# Android How to pass arguments to phone own application

Tags: android, google-maps, parameter-passing, android-activity

How to pass arguments from my activity to phone own Google maps application for giving directions point from my activity to Google map?

Comment: Pleas have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3517484/593709) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want your app to link to Google Maps displaying a specific location.

Google Maps has partial support for the [Geo URI scheme](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-00). See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) for the supported URIs.