# Launch maps app with directions and checkpoints

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

What I want to do is simple. I want to launch an intent like this.

```
        String url = "https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=47.295601,0.010586&daddr=47.295601,1.010586+to:47.295601,2.010586+to:47.295601,3.01058";
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(url));
```

The url is this:
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=47.295601,0.010586&daddr=47.295601,1.010586+to:47.295601,2.010586+to:47.295601,3.01058

The intent launches fine, and I get to choose between "Maps" and "Browser"-apps.

When I choose to open this intent with the "Browser", I can see the route with it's checkpoints without problems.

However, if i choose to open it with the Maps-app. It will say "No results for 47.295,1.010 to:47.295,2.010..... etc"

How to format the url to be able to open the Maps-app with navigation and checkpoints?

(Even if you open this link in your phone from the browser, it will ask you if you want to open the Maps-app. The same problem will occur if you do.)

thank you!

EDIT:
I clarify: I want to know how to get directions from point A to Y, via point B,C,D,E...etc.

How to get directions from point A to B I; know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

The following thing works for me. This is the google designated way for launching the google apps.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
       Uri.parse("geo:47.295601,1.010586?q=my+street+address&z=20"));
startActivity(intent);
```

The link for the same is below

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Following post is also providing lots of information on the same

[Launching Google Maps Directions via an intent on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662531/launching-google-maps-directions-via-an-intent-on-android)

[Launching Google Maps and Navigator from Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517484/launching-google-maps-and-navigator-from-android-app)

Hope this helps

Comment: Im sorry, but this is not solving my problem. I want to be able to get waypoint from point A to Y, via point B,C,D,E,F...... etc. This is only for directions from point A to B.

Comment: Hi ullstrm. This is pretty late but have you figured out the solution to this problem yet? If so, what did you end up doing?